# C++, detecting if mouse is idle-ing (short-time, 20ms)

Tags: c++, mouse, codeblocks

this is my first post!

I'm writing a C++ program to control main character in Touhou Games series; i'm making it for those who have hands disabilities and can't click arrow keys, but still can use mouse.

The player should trigger Arrow Keys with mouse movements (mouse goes left and left key is pressed, and so on..). I already did that part, but the character moves as if the arrow keys were pressed multiple times, so the character movements are a little clumsy and rough, not smooth and clean as if the key was HOLD.

My problem is that i have to know when mouse is idling/not moving (to understand how long the player wants to hold the arrow key -- the more the player slides the mouse in a direction, the more that arrow key is hold), but can't figure out how. Searching on Stackoverflow i've found GetLastInput function, but it triggers for EVERY input, and is not mouse-only related.

It should come out something like:

`while( *mousenotidling* )
{
    //holdbutton
}`

What would you suggest? How can i know when mouse is idling (for short-times, like 20ms)? (or if you suggest other solutions, every opinion is welcomed)

I'm writing it in C++, with Codeblock and GCC compiler, my OS is Windows 7 x86 :)

Comment: How about `int prev_x = 0, prev_y = 0; while (1) {int x = ..., y = ...; if (x == prev_x && y == prev_y) {mouse was moved} else {mouse wasn't moved} prev_x = x; prev_y = y;}`

Comment: Wow, uber-nice idea!! I can't make it exactly like that, in my case it would be more like: if(coordinates rest the same for 20ms){ //stopmoving }. I would need a timer to implement it, but it's no problem.

Thank you very much, this should work!! I'll update soon.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _`if (x == prev_x && y == prev_y) {mouse was moved} else {mouse wasn't moved}`_ Either I didn't get your idea or you swapped the then- and else-branch. However, it seems Alessandro _got_ the idea.

Comment: @Scheff Indeed, I accidentally swapped them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ...and Hasan was so kindly and copied your code sketch as is into his answer... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `TrackMouseEvent` and set the idling time to what is desire like 2000ms for 2sec idle time. Also you can use `GetLastInputInfo` to get the amount of milliseconds the last key or mouse movement was performed.

```
DWORD GetIdleTime() 
{ 
    LASTINPUTINFO pInput;   
    pInput.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO); 

    if (!GetLastInputInfo(&pInput))
    { 
        // any errors will be reported
    } 

    // return idle time in milliseconds
    return pInput.dwTime; 
}
```

Also you can try this one suggestion

```
int prev_x = 0, prev_y = 0; while (1) 
{int x = ..., y = ...; if (x == prev_x && y == prev_y) {mouse was moved} 
else {mouse wasn't moved} prev_x = x; prev_y = y;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I already tried GetIdleTime, but (if i'm not wrong), it does only return both keyboard and mouse, not standalones. I used BlackCat suggestion you quoted, and it works fine. Thank you again!